# PHP format number to money format. Decimal before last 2 digits

Tags: php

I need to format this to money format but not sure how. Can someone help

```
 <?php
 $input = "40025";
 echo $input;
```

I need to output 400.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this for example:

```
$input = 40025;
$output = $input/100;

$output = number_format($output, 2);

echo $output; // 400,25
```

Comment: from [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) - note: The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

Comment: I have used number_format and not money_format instead as you said

Answer (score 0):

You can format it with `sprintf`

```
printf("%.2f" 40025/100);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to number_format, you could also try `money_format` and specify a decimal before last two digits. USD example:

```
$input = "40025";
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');

echo money_format('%.2n', $input);
```

Comment: `money_format()` should not be used because it was deprecated in PHP7.4 and removed in PHP8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php